# How can I get rid of certain characters to the end of each line in a list?

Tags: python, linux

I currently have code which pulls from a file called output.txt. It reads through these lines and puts them in a list. If the word "Success" is found, it prints that line out. Currently it prints out the whole line. I want to be able to grab the first part of each line for my next task but I am having issues with getting rid of the rest of the line after a certain character.

For example the lines print:

```
user:pass Success Info
user:pass Success Info
```

etc..

I would like to just have it return:

```
user:pass
user:pass
user:pass
```

I am fairly new to python so I am struggling a bit with how to get rid of the rest of the line

I have tried splitting from the word Success on but that is not working right.

```
lines = []
with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if 'Success' in line:
            lines.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
for element in lines:
    print(element)
```

It currently prints `user:pass Success Info`

The actual output I want is `user:pass`

I am open to any suggestions

Answer (score 3):

Building on top of what you have, use `find`:

```
lines = []
with open("output.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if 'Success' in line:
            lines.append(line[:line.find("Success")-1])
for element in lines:
    print(element)
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, there should be a check mark next to the answer if you select this one as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know there won't be any spaces in what you want to print, and you know that what you want to print will always be before any spaces, you can try this:

```
some_text = 'user:pass Success'
split_text = some_text.split(' ')
print(split_text[0])
```